# Marketing Cloud SDK | Is Transactional Messaging API part of it?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, fuel-sdk, marketingcloudapi

I need to build a Micro Service on a different platform for sending emails. I need to use transactional messaging API.

I understand SFMC has SDK(http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/FuelSDK-Java/).

But does it support Transactional Messaging API services? Or which are the methods to do so?

Comment: I don't believe it includes the new Transactional Messaging API services. I had a quick run down on the classes and index but no luck. (http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/FuelSDK-Java/)

Comment: thats sad...I see last release was almost a year back from here: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java/releases